# \midrule, \bottomrule, etc do not extend until last columns of my table

Tags: tables, tabularx, rules, booktabs

I am observing strange behaviour in which `toprule, midrule, bottomrule` fail to extend until the last columns of my table.

In the MWE below, I reproduce the issue using `toprule,` & `bottomrule`

```tex
%%% Using MDPI journal template %%%
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \caption{My Table title} \label{tab1}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-\extralength}{0cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} ll *{10}{c}}
    \toprule
    &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 4}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 5} \\
    \cmidrule(r{1ex}){3-4} \cmidrule(r{1ex}){5-6} \cmidrule(r{1ex}){7-8} \cmidrule(r{1ex}){9-10} \cmidrule(r{1ex}){11-12}
    && {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} \\
    %\midrule
    \cmidrule{1-12} %\cmidrule(lr{1em}){1-12}
   \multirow{ 3}{*}{Group 1} 
       & \textit{First Round}  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
       & \textit{Second  Round}  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
       & \textit{Last  Round}  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\  
    \bottomrule     
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete MWE including your preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to use a `tabularx` environment but don't assign the `X` column type to any one of the 12 columns. You cannot possibly succeed in achieving the table's target width, viz., `\textwidth`.

Since line-breaking within cells -- which is what's enabled by the `X` column type -- does not appear to be a meaningful activity for the table at hand, I suggest you employ a `tabular*` environment instead and reorganize the headers in order to save a lot of (horizontal) space. I.e., something like this:

[image]

Observe that with this setup, there's no need to resort to the `adjustwidth` sledgehammer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mcii[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{My table title\strut} \label{tab1}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{10}{c} }
    \toprule
    Group & Round & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Experiments} \\
    \cmidrule{3-12}
    & & \mcii{1} & \mcii{2} & \mcii{3} & \mcii{4} & \mcii{5} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{7-8} \cmidrule{9-10} \cmidrule{11-12} 
    & & ABC & XYZ & ABC & XYZ & ABC & XYZ & ABC & XYZ & ABC & XYZ \\ 
    \midrule 
    1 & First  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
      & Second & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
      & Last   & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\  
    \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabulax) *without* an `X`-column doesn't make much sense. It's also the cause of the lines not drawing along the full table (you inherently restrict the `tabular` width to the first argument provided to `tabularx`).

The solution is to drop `tabularx` for this construction, and just set it as a regular `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{My Table title}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{10}{c}}
    \toprule
    & & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 1} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 2} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 3} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 4} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experiment 5} \\
    \cmidrule(r{1ex}){3-4} 
      \cmidrule(r{1ex}){5-6} 
      \cmidrule(r{1ex}){7-8} 
      \cmidrule(r{1ex}){9-10} 
      \cmidrule(r{1ex}){11-12}
      &                       & ABC  & XYZ  & ABC  & XYZ  & ABC  & XYZ  & ABC  & XYZ  & ABC  & XYZ  \\
    \midrule
            & \textit{First Round}  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
    Group 1 & \textit{Second Round} & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
            & \textit{Last Round}   & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\  
    \bottomrule     
  \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Judging by the position of the caption, the width of the `tabular` environment would appear to exceed `\textwidth` by a considerable margin [pun intended].

Comment: @Mico: Indeed! The OP uses `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](//ctan.org/pkg/changepage) to circumvent this somewhat, but that wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, version with use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{My table title\strut} 
\label{tab1}
    \begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
                 colspec = {@{} lQ[l, font=\itshape] *{10}{X[c]} @{}},
                 cell{1}{3} = {c=10}{c},
                 cell{1}{1,2} = {r=3}{h},
                 cell{2}{odd[3]} = {c=2}{}
                 }
    \toprule
        & Round &   Experiments
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule{3-12}
        &       & 1 &   & 2 &   & 3 &   & 4 &   & 5 &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-6} \cmidrule[lr]{7-8} \cmidrule[lr]{9-10} \cmidrule[lr]{11-12}
        &       & ABC   & XYZ   & ABC   & XYZ   & ABC   & XYZ   & ABC   & XYZ   & ABC   & XYZ \\
    \midrule
        & First & 0.87  & 0.67  & 0.50  & 0.61  & 0.47  & 0.58  & 0.49  & 0.50  & 0.41  & 0.52 \\
Group 1 & Second& 0.87  & 0.67  & 0.50  & 0.61  & 0.47  & 0.58  & 0.49  & 0.50  & 0.41  & 0.52 \\
        & Last  & 0.87  & 0.67  & 0.50  & 0.61  & 0.47  & 0.58  & 0.49  & 0.50  & 0.41  & 0.52 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides the good answers about the latex code, what about the content design?

As far as I can guess,  "Group 1 column" could have more sense in the table caption,  or as  header of the "Rounds" column.

On the other hand, especially if the table is for a two-column document (that could be not your case, being an example of why you should *always* show a MWE, not just the table), instead of showing data in a 10 x 3 array, why not in a 3x10? i.e., transposing the table. Just an example (MWE), probably not useful for you, but maybe for someone else fitting a table in narrow columns:

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,lipsum}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex plus 0.1ex minus .ex}
\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\def\abc{$\left\{\begin{array}{c} \mbox{ABC} \\ \mbox{XYZ} \\\end{array}\right.$}
\centering
\caption{My table title} 
\begin{tabular}{ccccc} \toprule
&  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Rounds Group 1} \\\cmidrule{2-4}
Experiment & First & Second & Last \\\midrule       
\multirow{2}{*}{1 \abc} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\\addlinespace  
\multirow{2}{*}{2 \abc} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\\addlinespace  
\multirow{2}{*}{3 \abc} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\\addlinespace  
\multirow{2}{*}{4 \abc} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\\addlinespace  
\multirow{2}{*}{5 \abc} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule     
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `tabularx` needs at least one `X` column, but there's no real use for it.

Repetitions should be avoided as much as possible in tables, here the (long) word “Experiment”: a further header makes the table more compact.

Also reserving a column for the group wastes precious space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]

\caption{My Table title} \label{tab1}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{10}{S[table-format=1.2]}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{Experiment} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{1}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{2}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{3}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{4}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{5} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{10-11}
& {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} & {ABC} & {XYZ} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\itshape Group 1} \\
First Round  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
Second Round & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
Last  Round  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\  
\midrule
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\itshape Group 2} \\
First Round  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
Second Round & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\
Last  Round  & 0.87 & 0.67 & 0.50 & 0.61 & 0.47 & 0.58 & 0.49 & 0.50 & 0.41 & 0.52 \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have just one group per table, put “Group 1” in the header's first column, to the left of “Experiment”.